# Perform calculations on a cell-by-cell basis

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to calculate on a cell by cell basis?

I am trying to add up the values in a range of columns `E10:E610` that are between 11,538 and 34,760, and then calculate 5.6 percent on them. However, in order to balance with another document, I would need to find 5.6 percent of each number individually in that range, and then round them individually.

Why? The file I'm supposed to balance with does the calculations and rounding individually on the numbers, so my calculations are a bit off. For example, 5.6% of 23,726 is 1,328.6, and that is rounded is 13,327. If I have 5 occurrences of 23,726 in my current file, the result will be 6,643.28, since Excel will add 1,328.6 five times and then find 5.6%.

However rounding individually will result in 6,645. Any help?

> `=ROUND(IF(J5="Yes",SUMPRODUCT((E10:I610>11538)*(E10:I610<=34760)*(A10:A610="No")‌​,E10:I610)*0.056+(COUNTIF(E10:I610,">34760")*34760)*0.056,""),0)`

I just realized that the round is done on the entire sum. Can I somehow calculate per cell and round per cell too?

Maybe I have to use VBA...

Comment: why **1,328.6** should become **13,327** .. why not 13,328 or 13,329 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do individual rounding of numbers in a range is to use an array formula.

Here's a simple example. Columns A:I shows the results of the individual rounding of each amount with the factor .056 and then adding up the results of the rounded products.

Cell M7 shows the same result using one formula: `=SUM(ROUND(K4:L6*.056,0))` As you can see, the `ROUND` function has as its first argument the product of the whole range of numbers with .056, with 0 as its second. (The rounding error for this small example is about 0.8.) As an array formula, the expression must be entered with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

[image]

While your formula is a lot more complicated, the same method can still be applied, though it may not be possible to use `SUMPRODUCT` as you have. You would just use `SUM` instead. (Looking only at the `SUMPPRODUCT(....)*.056 piece, I would probably do something like

```
=SUM((E10:I610>11538)*(E10:I610<=34760)*(A10:A610="No")*ROUND(E10:I610*0.056,0))
```

Comment: Wow this seems to work for the sum parts, now how do i add in my countif statement? The reason for the countif is for all the numbers greater than 34760, they are supposed to be equated to 34760. So i placed the countif then multiplied the number by 34760, then fount the percentage of that and added it to the rest of the formula. So for instance if in the cells i had two occurrences of 40000, those would count as (2*34760)*0.056.
How do I add this and the if statement to the formula you produced?

Comment: Try this: +SUM((E10:I610>34760)*ROUND(34760*0.056,0)). If I'm following your formula, you would still have the IF(J5="Yes",....,0) bracketing the summing.

Comment: You are a boss chuff, this worked perfectly. Please keep up the good work buddy. Again...thanks a million.

Comment: You know i know this works but just didnt manage to set it up right, can you write the entire formula including the IF(J5="Yes",..)portion please. That would be a great help.

Comment: See if this works: =IF(J5="YES",SUM((E10:I610>11538)*(E10:I610<=34760)*(A10:A610="No")*ROUND(E10:I610*0.056,0))+SUM((E10:I610>34760)*ROUND(34760*0.056,0)),0)

Comment: No sorry buddy...getting the #NAME? error.

Comment: Like a BOSS. Thank you Chuff, you fixed it. Just had a problem when i copied and pasted it but it works. Thank you for taking the time to tackle this with me. Truly a great person, keep up the good work buddy (Thumbs up).

Comment: The weird thing is the formula works in my test sheet but when i place in my active sheet i get a value error this is frustrating.